# Screen flickering and laptop goes to sleep

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, suspend, flicker

I dual booted my laptop with Ubuntu 18.04 along with Windows 10, just a few days back. My laptop is Dell Inspiron 5567, 8GB Ram, 1TB HDD and Intel HD graphics. So, after booting, the laptop screen suddenly flickers and then the laptop goes to sleep. I don't know why this is happening. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably the display driver or the refresh rate.

Go to Preferences->Display/Monitors and check the refresh rate.  You will need to determine what it needs to be for your monitor (Google)

If that's okay, check the version of the display driver you are using.

```
sudo lshw -c video | grep 'configuration'
sudo lshw -c video
```

Then you will need to determine what's supposed to be there.  This means determining what your graphic card is.

Comment: Tried this, still the issue remains the same

Comment: Please post the output of the above two commands in your original question, and then comment here so I know you've updated it.   Also, please indicate the exact model of your video card, and add a screenshot of the video driver that Windows is using (Device Manager - properties).  This can be sorted out.